# How to get thread names from a core dump?

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, gdb, coredump

I have a multi-threaded program, where each thread is assigned a unique name with help of `pthread_setname_np`. If I attach to a running program with gdb, I can see their names:

```
(gdb) i th
  Id   Target Id                                            Frame
* 1    Thread 0x7f883dba1200 (LWP 3867757) "main"           __pthread_clockjoin_ex (threadid=140222870320896, thread_return=0x0, clockid=<optimized out>, abstime=<optimized out>, block=<optimized out>)
    at pthread_join_common.c:145
  2    Thread 0x7f883477f700 (LWP 3867759) "log_aggregator" 0x00007f883dc8026f in __GI___clock_nanosleep (clock_id=clock_id@entry=0, flags=flags@entry=0, req=0x7f883477b220, rem=0x7f883477b220)
    at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/clock_nanosleep.c:78
```

Note `main` and `log_aggregator` names. However, If I make a core dump and then load this dump with gdb, I don't see the names:

```
$ gcore 3867757
...
Saved corefile core.3867757
...
$ gdb -c core.3867757 my_program
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 10.2-0ubuntu1~20.04~1) 10.2
...
(gdb) i th
  Id   Target Id                           Frame
* 1    Thread 0x7f883dba1200 (LWP 3867757) __pthread_clockjoin_ex (threadid=140222870320896, thread_return=0x0, clockid=<optimized out>, abstime=<optimized out>, block=<optimized out>)
    at pthread_join_common.c:145
  2    Thread 0x7f883477f700 (LWP 3867759) 0x00007f883dc8026f in __GI___clock_nanosleep (clock_id=clock_id@entry=0, flags=flags@entry=0, req=0x7f883477b220, rem=0x7f883477b220)
    at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/clock_nanosleep.c:78
```

How do I get thread names in this case? Or should I create core file differently to put them in the core file? I examined `coredump_filter` option, but did not find anything related. I also discovered [this discussion](https://gdb.sourceware.narkive.com/OLqLGn67/thread-names-in-7-7-using-info-threads-command) at narkive mailing list archive, but it does not provide an answer, only a suggestion that this might be impossible.

Comment: Did you read the manual page for `pthread_setname_np`? Specifically, the NOTES part? It explains exactly what's going on here.

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you. My next question would be is there any way this `/proc/self/task/[tid]/comm` file might be included in the core dump file?

Comment: It seems logical to me that: 1) this requires direct kernel support, the kernel itself produces the coredump, 2) this requires direct support in gdb, to read it, and 3) if direct kernel support is available then I would expect gdb to support it automatically, without any further action being required. It's a no-brainer: there is no backward compatibility issue introduced by implementing it. Therefore, if this is not already happening by itself, the answer must be "no".

Comment: The answer might also be - no one just cared to implement it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My next question would be is there any way this /proc/self/task/[tid]/comm

The `/proc/.../comm` is not a real file, it's a representation of kernel data structures related to this task generated on-demand (when you try to read that "file").

The `current->comm` field that you are looking for is not mentioned in the [binfmt_elf.c](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/fs/binfmt_elf.c) file (which is where other `core` dumping code is), so it's *probably* not saved.

In fact this is easily confirmed by running a test program generating a random string, calling `pthread_setname_np`, dumping `core` and then running `strings -a core | grep $string`, which produces no output.

There is no *fundamental* reason the `current->comm` can not be saved in the `core`, but currently it isn't.

P.S. Usually looking at `thread apply all where` is enough to distinguish different threads, so the unique thread name is redundant and unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks! I have a bunch of working threads that are spawned in exactly the same way doing exactly the same jobs and I dont know other way to distinguish them except by name.